# why can I use map on a function here?

Tags: scala

I don't understand why this code compiles :

```
def lift[A,B](f: A => B): Option[A] => Option[B] = _ map f
```

If I do :

```
val f: Int => Double = _.toDouble
```

Then `lift(f)` works fine, but `f map f` gives an error : `error: value map is not a member of Int => Double`

Comment: `lift(f)` is equivalent to function `(x: T) => x map f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why this code compiles :
>
> ```
> def lift[A,B](f: A => B): Option[A] => Option[B] = _ map f
> ```

It's short for

```
def lift[A,B](f: A => B): Option[A] => Option[B] = (o: Option[A]) => o map f
```

Method `lift` returns a function that:
- takes an `Option[A]`
- modifies that option's contents using some function `f: A => B`
- returns the result, `Option[B]`

So, when you "lift" some function `f: A => B`, you basically upgrade it from `A => B` to `Option[A] => Option[B]`. When this new upgraded function is given `o: Option[A]`, it will map that option's content into `Option[B]` (by using `f: A => B` which was provided when original function was being upgraded).

> If I do:
>
> ```
> val f: Int => Double = _.toDouble
> ```
>
> Then lift(f) works fine, but f map f gives an error `error: value map is > not a member of Int => Double`

Yes, because you cannot *map over a function*. You can only *map over something by using a function* (by the way, things you can map over are called *functors*).

What you want to do is:

1. Define some function *f* (you defined `val f: Int => Double = _.toDouble`)
2. Use lift to "upgrade" you function f from `Int => Double` to `Option[Int] => Option[Double]`
3. Use your new upgraded function to map over an `Option[Int]`, thereby transforming it into an `Option[Double]`.

So:

```
val f: Int => Double = _.toDouble
val upgraded = lift(f)
println(upgraded(Some(8))) // prints Some(8.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `lift` function simply lifts your function `f: A=> B` to the function on some other domain, in this case it is `Option[_]`. So, your implementation of `lift` gives you a function f': Option[A] => Option[B], and because Option has the `map` function, you can call it on the first input parameter (this is the 'underscore').

You don't have to call `f map f`. What you do is lifting your f function:

```
val f: Int => Double = _.toDouble
val lifted = lift(f)
lifted(Some(42)) //it should be Some(42.0)
```